# How to myslq select from two rows

Tags: mysql, sql

im trying to select from two columns.
i try as below. it is not correct right.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE company OR contact LIKE Alfreds ";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You need server side code that reads data from request and creates a sql query. On client side you can use javascript with ajax that puts the selected data into the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select from two column, you can try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE company LIKE '%Alfreds%' OR contact LIKE '%Alfreds%'`.

Comment: Heads up. While this works, it is absolutely a nightmare for performance.

Comment: You are right,but I dont think he can understand fulltext index or es,if he do,he will not ask question like this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "*" you have to write the names of the two columns and then the data you are looking for, if instead you want to averer different data from two different columns you have to create a view, try googling, I'm sure you'll find what you need, but remember, mysql doesn't work with html's tables.

Ex.:
Select two column:
SELECT column1,column2 FROM table ...

Create a view:
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table ...